# need to pull a specific record

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

There is 1 record having duplicate values except in 1 column having x and y

record       status
XXXXXXXXXX    A
XXXXXXXXXX    B

Need to pull A only and remove the other duplicate B

Select record
case
when status in ("'a', 'b'") then ('a')
from xyz

Comment: Hi - please update your question to show some sample data (formatted as a table) that illustrates your issue and, if it is not obvious, explain the logic necessary to achieve what you want - based on the sample data

Answer (score 0):

Let suppose you have data as below where Status is repeating for First column

[image]

but you are interesting in the status which is of having lower value as given below:

[image]

In this case following SQL may help. Here, we are partitioning on key field and ordering the Status so that we can apply filter on rank to get desired result.

```
WITH sampleData AS
 (SELECT '1234' as Field1,  'A' as STATUS UNION ALL 
  SELECT '1234',  'C' UNION ALL
  SELECT '5678', 'A' UNION ALL 
  SELECT '5678',  'B' )

 select * except(rank) from (
 select *, rank() over (partition by Field1 order by STATUS ASC) rank from sampleData)
 where rank = 1
 order by Field1
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select * from sampledata
qualify 1 = row_number() over win
window win as (partition by field1 order by if(status='A',1,2) )
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]